# How to make HTTP POST call in Angular2 and print the response

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am new to Angular2 and buuilding a sample project to learn it. I am curently looking at how to make HTTP calls in Angular2 and found this code snippet example:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.http.post('http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/poc-post/', 
                       JSON.stringify({firstName:'Joe',lastName:'Smith'}),
                       {headers:headers})
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
.subscribe((res:Person) => this.postResponse = res);
```

I am not sure what the subscribe does, but my main objective is to print the response. From this code I can see the response, but I am unsure how to "isolate and access it" (I hope that makes sense). My question is how would I print the response to the console?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My question is how would I print the response to the console?

You can just print `res`:

```
.subscribe((res:Person) => { this.postResponse = res; console.log(res); });
```

[Click here for **demo plunk**.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ooT9YyaQbNbVS4hgSdhD?p=preview)

---

> I am not sure what the subscribe does (...)

The result of [`Http.post(...)` (link)](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/Http-class.html#!#post) is an [`Observable<Response>` (link)](http://reactivex.io/RxJS/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html).

In your code, you pick the result of the POST (an `Observable<Response>`) and call [`.map()` (link)](http://reactivex.io/RxJS/function/index.html#static-function-map) on it. In your case, you do that to parses the response as JSON and transform it into an object:

```
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
```

Now, the result of `.map()` is also an `Observable<Response>`. That's when you call `subscribe`.

[`subscribe()` (link)](http://reactivex.io/RxJS/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-subscribe) is a method of the [`Observable` (link)](http://reactivex.io/RxJS/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) class, and it allow you to, tipically, "register" or "subscribe" three functions that will handle/read the results (or "events") this observable emits - they are called (*on*)`next`, (*on*)`error` and (*on*)`complete`.

So, the code using `.subscribe()` is usually:

```
.subscribe(
     (response) => {
            /* this function is executed every time there's a new output */
           console.log("VALUE RECEIVED: "+response);
     },
     (err) => {
            /* this function is executed when there's an ERROR */
            console.log("ERROR: "+err);
     },
     () => {
            /* this function is executed when the observable ends (completes) its stream */
            console.log("COMPLETED");
     }
 );
```

So, in order to fully understand Angular2's Http, I suggest you read some resources on **[RxJS and Observables](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS)**. When you get back from it, things will be much simpler, I promise (no pun intended :).

Comment: Thank you for the great Answer! One question, as I would like to only print the response once it is complete, in the last function (completed) how do I access the response inside there?

Comment: Tipically, an http call only sends one response, meaning the first function (the one with `"VALUE RECEIVED: "`) will only be called once and the third function (with `"Completed"`) will be called right after it.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: Please, what if I don't want to use the subscribe? Is there a way around the subscribe?

Comment: @OniyaDaniel why would you want that?